# Possible to multiply or concat JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React along with Font Awesome to create a row of stars. I have a function that takes a number and produces that many stars. I'm trying to find the best way to do this within a react component. Basically, I need to multiply the JSX element by a number to get it to repeat dynamically based on what's passed in:

```js
reviewStars(num) {
    const star = <i className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>;
    const getStarCount = star.repeat(num);
    return getStarCount;
  };
```

If the JSX was a string, this would work, but because it's not, I can't call repeat on it (error says star is not a function). I could wrap it in single quotes '' and then replace those, but wondering if there is a better handle to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
reviewStars(num) {
  let stars = [];
  for(let i= 0; i < num; i++) {
    stars.push(<i key={i} className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>);
  }
  return (
    <div>{stars}</div>
  );
};
```

edit:
remember to add key to lists

Comment: Great thank you. I also had tried something similar to this for loop. I had no idea that you could just render an array of elements like that (<div>{stars}</div>) . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Array.from() method creates an array with specified length. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) here.

```
<div>
{ Array.from({ length: num }, (_, i) =>
    <i key={i} className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>) }
</div>
```

The mapper assigns a key from the second argument (index) to each child element.

Comment: Care for any explanation or reference to improve the question?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking exactly for an elegant solution like this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to maintain validity of JSX, you would first need to wrap sibling elements in a parent element, either a `<span>` or a `<div>`.

Afterwards you would have to loop `num` times and repeat your JSX for the star, accumulating it in a variable that you will return inside that wrapper.

Something like this should do the trick for you

```js
reviewStars(num) {
   let stars = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       stars.push(<i className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" key={i} />;
   }

   return (
       <span>
          {stars}
       </span>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{[...Array(num)].map((_, i) => ( <i key={i}><i/> ))}
```

Comment: Hey can! Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for the answer. A good answer shouldn't be code-only but also include an explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer